# Excel-VBA to SQLite3 through ODBC Driver: primary database + attached database

Tags: vba, excel, sqlite, odbc

I'm trying to connect from Excel-VBA to SQLite3 database through ODBC (Windows 10 x64).

I use Christian Werner's SQLite ODBC driver v 0.9999 (http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc) - as manual says I've installed both install both 32 and 64Bit versions of the driver.

Connecting to one database is ok:

```
ConnectionString = "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=c:\first.db;"
```

Connecting to 2 databases (SQLite provides ability to connect to primary database + attached database) is also ok:

```
ConnectionString = "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=c:\first.db;Attach=c:\second.db;"
```

but looks like VBA don't see tables from attached database - the following query fails:

```
SELECT * FROM [second].[table_name_in_second_db];
```

Does that SQLite ODBC driver supports attach database in connection string?
Or maybe I use incorrect syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't handle attachments thru the connection. The primary database is handled in the connection properties. Once you have a valid connection you're essentially using sqlite engine. (the driver is a wrapper for sqlite.dll) Therefore you can attach databases as sql statements.

cn.execute "attach database 'C:\filename.db' as db"